# CSS opacity filter faster than opacity property?

Tags: performance, css-filters

On [this html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/) article, it states that

> In general the CSS ‘opacity’ property isn’t hardware accelerated, but some browsers that implement filters using hardware acceleration will accelerate the filter version of opacity for much better performance.

This seems to imply that in performance-intensive applications, one should use the opacity filter instead of the opacity property. For example, I'm rendering a canvas under an image with an opacity property of 0.5. Should I be using the filter instead? How could one measure performance gains when using this filter property, and on what platforms might there be a noticeable improvement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, CSS3 filter effects are [still a draft standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/) and [their browser support varies](http://css3clickchart.com/#filters). So think twice whether you really need them (e.g., [CSS Filters in the Real World article](http://blog.kaelig.fr/post/47025488367/css-filters-in-the-real-world) (04.2013) reports rendering artifacts).
[Hardware acceleration in Webkit](http://www.slideshare.net/joone/hardware-acceleration-in-webkit) and [GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome) give an overview of their implementations and both suggest there's no discrimination against CSS2 or CSS3 (I'd be surprised if there was).

Second, [a review in PC magazine](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2413635,00.asp) (01.2013) shows results of some online benchmarks by IE and Firefox teams. There are canvas, particle and CSS (rotation) benchmarks. The Maxthon (uses WebKit) and Opera versions tested there do not support acceleration so they give a hint on the performance gain. Regarding the transparency: it's orders of magnitude less computations than resampling so you shouldn't notice any difference for this specific operation.

Comment: The article that Trey referred to discusses not IE's propritary filters, but CSS3 Filter Effects (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) currently supported in WebKit- and Blink-based browsers. Interestingly, the same article states below (in 'Availability in modern browsers' section, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/#toc-availability) that `opacity` filter 'can be slow' in Chrome.

Comment: The html5rocks article is dated May 2012, it's definitely obsolete.

Comment: Chromium Blog article from June 2012 states that Chromium 19 already had support for accelerated CSS filters: http://blog.chromium.org/2012/06/accelerated-css-filters-landed-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Paul Irish says here that opacity is one of the few CSS properties that ***is*** GPU accelerated: https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/aTRerYcZpts

And also, there is a severe lack of support for filters across browsers as can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter), though opacity is supported across the board: http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity.

Not to mention the opacity property is just so much easier to use.

I'd stick with what you've got.